# How do you prevent android apps from crashing when you have many activities?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android and am making an app which features many activities and a user prefs get edited during almost every one, and it seems that it randomly starts crashing 6 or 7 activities in, and opening up a different activity from a couple of pages ago, but only sometimes. I do everything exactly the same each time and I don't know what causes it to crash. Usually it will crash back to a different intent and let me continue from there. Here is the logcat after a crash:

```
10-31 13:01:52.122 2542-2542/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-31 13:01:52.253 2542-2542/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1>
10-31 13:01:52.253 2542-2542/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1>
10-31 13:01:52.360 2542-2542/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-31 13:01:52.516 2542-2558/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
10-31 13:01:52.517 2542-2542/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa66e01b0, tid 2542
10-31 13:01:52.522 2542-2542/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-31 13:01:52.569 2542-2558/? D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa66e0260, tid 2558
10-31 13:01:52.578 2542-2558/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-31 13:01:52.592 2542-2558/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-31 13:01:52.602 2542-2558/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-31 13:01:52.602 2542-2558/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa66b4b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: While those are lines from LogCat, they do not pertain to your problem. You are looking for a Java stack trace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Thanks. Having out of memory error, oh no. How have I seen apps that must use so much more memory then?

Comment: They're doing a better job of memory management, which is a complex topic in Android. On [my videos page](https://commonsware.com/videos) there is a conference presentation that I delivered last year on memory management that may be of use to you.